# Highpitch buzzing sound and audio record out put being low

Tags: audio

I set my laptop window8 microphone to 2 High Definition Audio Device on a max 100 it gives a very annoying high pith buzzing sound But reduce to 80 its gone.Also when the boost  slide on, on any level it will reappear.
Along with it, my audioplayback voice output is very low even when set vol. 100.
I am testing this sound microphone output unto my Screencast-o-matic free version.
Anyone's reply of resolution is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Every microphone has it's own noise floor. When you apply microphone boost, it literally boosts up all signals from the microphone — including it's noise floor and any background or signal noise; this is what you hear.

Ideally, when microphone boost is disabled and microphone volume is set to 100%, background noise should be minimal. But many laptops (even expensive ones) are supplied with low quality microphones with high noise floors. There might be a noise-reduction option in you laptop's microphone settings, but it often distorts sound quality in a significant way.

If your built-in microphone is noisy, I recommend either purchasing a decent USB microphone, or disabling boost and setting the microphone to around ~80% volume (and talking louder). There is not much else you can do.